# Get node.js server-side object available in client-side javascript code

Tags: javascript, node.js, uipath

I played around with [**UiPath Orchestrator package**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uipath-orchestrator). And the connection worked out with the installed node.js package.

Anyway now I need to implement it in my website in a way where I get access it from a simple `html` site.

There I struggle a bit with getting it to run. This is how I would like to use it:

index.html:

```
<html>
  ...
  <button onclick="test()">Do something</button>  
  ...
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  ...
</html>
```

server.js: (I start with `node server.js`)

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');
const port = 6543;
const path = require('path');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  let filePath = path.join(
      __dirname,
      req.url === "/" ? "index.html" : req.url
  );
  let extName = path.extname(filePath);
  let contentType = 'text/html';
  switch (extName) {
      case '.js':
          contentType = 'text/javascript';
          break;
  }
  console.log(`File path: ${filePath}`);
  console.log(`Content-Type: ${contentType}`);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': contentType});
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
  readStream.pipe(res);
});
server.listen(port, (err) => {
...
});
```

scripts.js:

```
function test() {
  ...
  // get the orch object here without defining it here as it contains credentials
  var orchestratorInstance = new Orchestrator({
    tenancyName: string (optional),
    usernameOrEmailAddress: string (required),
    password: string (required),
    hostname: string (required),
    isSecure: boolean (optional, default=true),
    port: integer (optional, [1..65535], default={443,80} depending on isSecure),
    invalidCertificate: boolean (optional, default=false),
    connectionPool: number (optional, 0=unlimited, default=1)
  });
}
```

This works. So the test function is fired.

But now I would like to get the `Orchestrator` object (like shown here https://www.npmjs.com/package/uipath-orchestrator).

How to do it in the best way?

Maybe just pass-through that object to the `scripts.js` file itself? But how to do that with `window` or `global` and would that be a proper solution?

I need the server-side generated object as it contains credentials that may not be delivered to client-side.

Comment: You could embed your node generated javascript into a script file of the html.

Comment: And how to do that with the object? Some example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works perfectly together with **[UiPath-Orchestrator nodejs](https://github.com/UiPath/orchestrator-nodejs)**.

So just use:

```
var util = require('util');
var Orchestrator = require('uipath-orchestrator');
var orchestrator = new Orchestrator({
     tenancyName: 'test',           // The Orchestrator Tenancy
     usernameOrEmailAddress: 'xxx',// The Orchestrator login
     password: 'yyy',               // The Orchestrator password
     hostname: 'host.company.com', // The instance hostname
     isSecure: true,                // optional (defaults to true)
     port: 443, // optional (defaults to 80 or 443 based on isSecure)
     invalidCertificate: false, // optional (defaults to false)
     connectionPool: 5 // options, 0=unlimited (defaults to 1)
});
var apiPath = '/odata/Users';
var apiQuery = {};
orchestrator.get(apiPath, apiQuery, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error: ' + err);
    }
    console.log('Data: ' + util.inspect(data));
});
```

and extract the `orchestrator` object to your `node.js` code.

It also works together with **Orchestrator Cloud** (if you don't have the on-prem), see [**here**](https://github.com/UiPath/orchestrator-nodejs/issues/7) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

A crude example, but to give an idea, of embedding a script file into html.
Ideally you'd use express to load a webpage, but this is purely to describe usecase.

You could do the same with an end body tag, or end head tag.

```js
const http = require('http'),
const fs = require('fs');

const html = fs.readFileSync('./file.html'); 
const obj = fs.readFileSync('./script.js'); 

const htmlWithScript = html.replace(/\<\/html\s*\>/,`<script>${obj}</script></html>`);
// const htmlWithScript = `<html><head><script>${obj}</script></head><body> my html stuff ...</body></html>`

http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(htmlWithScript);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(8000);
```

Comment: It looks good and maybe it could work. But I'm not able to load the HTML file and giving it the object. Maybe could you extend the example and show me how to do it when the HTML code is in a separate file?

Comment: I get an error. But anyway this will not work at all. You try to include the source code into the HTML. But as I said, the script.js file contains a credential. This has to be  executed server-side and than the object if possible going to client-side. How to do that?

Comment: This isn't a complete solution, its how to solve the problem of embedding a script file into your html. Ask a new question with more thorough requirements

Comment: Sorry when it was not clear enough. But that's a requirement. Sure simply require a file and using it is easy. But it's just the object that is returned needed for security reason. I Updated the question.

Comment: So just use replace method as I have above inside your createServer.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Maybe you could show that with an self-made object.

Comment: Looking at the codebase for orchestrator particularly this will only work in node so pointless having an instance locally in embedded script in html. https://github.com/UiPath/orchestrator-nodejs/blob/master/lib/restHelper.js. What are you using it for that an alternative can't do? Why not construct a similar logic building your own library using the xmlhttprequest object, fetch or axios on the client side?

Comment: Well, so there is no easy way. But what is best way being able to hide the credentials. I'm kind of new to node.js so what is best practice here. At the end I would like to be able to have some button that are calling functions with the Orchestrator object. Is this basically a bad approach?